# CardView animation

Tags: java, android, class, animation

so I have my app that displays the content in cardviews, these views are linked to an animation and it works fine. But my question here is how can I make it work like the animation in the "Google Now" app? Like it slides in from the bottom.

So like when you slide up from the home button, it open Google Now. But then all the cards slide up, anyone know how I can achieve this. I've looked everywhere but I don't know the animation layout.

I've been using this anim -

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="1000" android:duration="80"/>
</set>
```

which slides it up but its not quite like the google now one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a ListView, you can check out the ListViewAnimations samples here:
https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

The Google Cards Example tries to mimic the original Google Now animations.